# Can I eat the lemons after I have used them as a battery?

Tags: home-experiment, safety

After completing the lemon battery experiment, can I eat the lemons when I'm done?

More broadly, what will happen to the lemons? What are the chemical reactions, what chemicals might be present/missing after running my lemons as a zinc/copper battery? Would it be poisonous, or just unpleasant?

Comment: Hmm, a single down vote amongst the ups. Feedback greatly appreciated if available :)

Comment: Wasn't me but I'll bet somebody thought there's no way this could be a good idea. The first answer reveals it's nowhere near that cut and dried, so I don't care for the downvote either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a lemon battery, the zinc from the galvanized nail is giving up electrons and transitioning into an aqueous state:

$$\ce{Zn → Zn^2+ + 2e−}$$

While zinc is entering the electrolyte, two positively charged hydrogen ions ($\ce{H+}$) from the citric acid with two electrons at the copper electrode's surface and form an uncharged hydrogen molecule $\ce{H2}$:

$$\ce{2H+ + 2e− → H2}$$

While zinc is a mineral our bodies need, I wouldn't recommend using this as a source of zinc. Also, [zinc toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_toxicity) is a thing, so without knowing the dose you're taking, you risk poisoning yourself.

---

[Lemon Battery Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery)

Comment: Unless you manage to dissolve a significant part of your zinc electrodes into the lemons, zinc toxicity is probably not a serious concern. As the Wikipedia article you linked to notes, zinc supplements containing over 0.15 grams of zinc *per day* have been commonly used with no lasting harmful effects. That's equivalent to about half a square centimeter of 0.5 mm zinc sheet entirely dissolved into the lemon. Mind you, I probably still wouldn't eat the lemons myself; if nothing else, I suspect they may taste pretty nasty.